# How to use MySQL "REPLACE" function in Kohana 3.2 query builder?

Tags: mysql, kohana

How can I get code like this "REPLACE INTO table ... " using query builder in Kohana 3.2. Is that implemented or I'll have to implement it on my own.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QBuilder has no `REPLACE INTO` feature, because its not a standard SQL query. You can create query with `DB::query()` method:

`DB::query(NULL, 'replace into ...');`